# load fixtures phpunit test for a dummy

Tags: phpunit, fixtures

thanks to take a look here. I am starting get involved in a project and I need to create the tests for the code I've written. I have not too much experience with tests.

I've written this file:
tests/fixtures/visitante_boletin.yml

```
1:
    id_localizacion: 60
    email: emailconfirmado@server.net
    estado_confirmacion: 1
    fecha_creacion: 2013-02-03 12:01:49
    fecha_confirmacion: 2013-02-03 12:01:49
    fecha_cancelacion: 
    token: 343fbb5f15709935470ba3b7524068af8544776d924b0bd45c2558a7eb5c8082f0bef31402b773fa
```

and this test:
tests/libraries/com/arteinformado/service/front/SuscribeServiceTest.php
...

```
    const SINCONFIRMAR = 0;
    const CONFIRMADO = 1;
    const CANCELADO = 2;
...
    public function testShouldGetAllSuscriptionsWithStateCONFIRMADO() {
        $suscriptors = $this->_suscribeService->getAllSuscriptionsWithState(self::CONFIRMADO);
        $this->assertNotEmpty($suscriptors);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($suscriptors));
    } 
...
```

When I run the test I get an error at the assertNotEmpty, so I don't know if fixture data are being loaded or what's going on, since the method it is testing it is quite simple and should be ok.

```
public function getAllSuscriptionsWithState($estado_confirmacion) {
    $suscriptors = array();

    $query = $this->db->get_where('visitante_boletin', array('estado_confirmacion' => $estado_confirmacion));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $suscriptor = $this->_dbRowToVisitanteBoletin($row);
        array_push($suscriptors, $suscriptor);
    }

    return $suscriptors;

}
```

Any help guide will be really appreciate.

Thanks in advance. Cheers,
·_-

Answer (score 0):

The [PHPUnit-documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) is [your friend](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html#set-up-fixture).

You didn't mention it, but have you:

- installed the DbUnit-extension
- let your test-classes extend PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
- provided your test-classes with a getConnection()- and getDataSet()-method

That definitely is working for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I checked the doc, but finally what I got wrong it was the tables attribute missing.